# Experience Edge XM OAuth Credentials "Service not enabled within domain"

Tags: graphql, xm-cloud, jwt-token

I am trying to generate JWT token by using the oAuh client credentials XM cloud. referring [JWT for Experience Edge](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/request-a-jwt-for-experience-edge-xm-using-oauth.html) link.
getting `Service not enabled within domain: https://auth.sitecorecloud.io` error with `403 forbidden` status code.
[image].

Can someone please help me, how can I enable the service domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, the audience url is incorrect in sitecore documentation.
it is should be `https://api.sitecorecloud.io` and it's worked for me.

Sharing here for reference.